# When is the implementation of Retrofit.create removed again?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I create an api endpoint implementation like

```
RepoListRestApi repoListApiImpl = retrofit.create(RepoListRestApi.class)
```

When is repoListApiImpl removed again in garbage collection?
Do I need create a customer scope in dagger for it to ensure that garbage collection removes it?

Comment: it is removed same way as any other object regardless of variable name or type.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then I create a subcomponent to inject that reference.